# Improove function of multiple replacement by RegEx in range of cells

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use this code for multiple regex replace in range of cells, but it work too slow. I know that it better to use "push Array" instead of Range.getValue, but I really dont understand how it works and I will be grateful for any help.

```
 function patternizer(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var firstrow = 1
      var lastrow = 1000
      var column = 11
      regexrep(/( |)\d+-\d+/,'',firstrow,lastrow,column);
      regexrep(/\d{4}-\d{4}/,'',firstrow,lastrow,column);
      regexrep(/.*?(\D\d.*)/,'$1',firstrow,lastrow,column);
      regexrep(/(.*\d\D).*/,'$1',firstrow,lastrow,column);
      regexrep(/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/,'',firstrow,lastrow,column);
    }

    function regexrep(rxp,rxR,firstrow,lastrow,column){
//(regex pattern, replace pattern, firstrow, lastrow, column)
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var r1 = new RegExp(rxp);
      for (i=firstrow; i<=lastrow; i++){
        try{
          var tr = ss.getRange(i, column)
          var t = tr.getValue()
          t = t.replace(r1, rxR);
          tr.setValue(t)
        }catch(e){
        }
      }
    }
```

Data for test:

```
Plate 21410 T15K6 (16h10h3h25) (to end and keyway cutters, reamers and tsekovok)
Plate 24070 BK8 (10h5h3) (for disk and end-end cylindrical. Mills to modular machine tools)
Plate 36410 BK8 (16h6h3h18) (for mechanical, slip-and end mills with spiral tooth)
Knife torts.frez 2020-0161 R6M5
Knife 2020-0162 for tripartite cutter d100-224h12 (23,8h11h4,72) R6M5 grooved wedge left
Knife 2020-0164 for tripartite cutter d100-224h14 (23,8h13h4,72) R6M5 grooved wedge left
Knife 2020-0165 for tripartite cutter d100-125 (23,8h15h4,72) R6M5 grooved wedge right
Knife 2020-0166 for tripartite cutter d100-125 (23,8h15h4,72) R6M5 grooved wedge left
Plate 21350 BK8 (14h8h3h25) (to end and keyway cutters, reamers and tsekovok)
Plate 36390 BK8 (21h6h3h24) (for mechanical, slip-and end mills with spiral tooth)
Knife 2020-0167 for tripartite cutter d160-250 (28,3h15h5,72) R6M5 grooved wedge right
Knife 2020-0172 to the end mill d125-315 (28,3h28,5h5,72) R6M5 grooved wedge left
Cutter veneer. c / x 3
Knife 2020-0026 to the end mill d160-315 (33,8h25,5h7,72) R6M5 grooved wedge left
Intermediate ring d16, D27, L 2mm to the mandrel for milling machines GOST15071-75
Knife 2020-0169 for tripartite cutter d100-315 (28,3h26,5h5,72) R6M5 grooved wedge right
Knife 2020-0022 to the end mill d80-100 (28,3h18,5h5,72) R6M5 grooved wedge left
Intermediate ring d16, D27, L10mm to the mandrel for milling machines GOST15071-75
Intermediate ring d22, D34, L 1mm to the mandrel for milling machines GOST15071-75
Intermediate ring d22, D34, L 2.0mm to the mandrel for milling machines GOST15071-75
Intermediate ring d22, D34, L 2.3mm to the mandrel for milling machines
Intermediate ring d22, D34, L 3mm to the mandrel for milling machines GOST15071-75
Intermediate ring d22, D50, L 5mm to the mandrel for milling machines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really like to have some data to check this on because I'm not one of those programmers who gets things 100% right the first time. But here's my first pass solution and I think it will work.

```
function patternizer()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var firstrow = 1
  var lastrow = 1000
  var column = 11
  regexrep(/( |)\d+-\d+/,'',firstrow,lastrow,column);
  regexrep(/\d{4}-\d{4}/,'',firstrow,lastrow,column);
  regexrep(/.*?(\D\d.*)/,'$1',firstrow,lastrow,column);
  regexrep(/(.*\d\D).*/,'$1',firstrow,lastrow,column);
  regexrep(/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/,'',firstrow,lastrow,column);
}
//(regex pattern, replace pattern, firstrow, lastrow, column)
function regexrep(rxp,rxR,firstrow,lastrow,column){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  //Ranges start at1
  var rng = ss.getRange(firstrow,column,lastrow,1);
  var rngA = rng.getValues(); //[[],[],[],[],....] Arrays start at zero
  var r1 = new RegExp(rxp);
  for(i = 0;i < lastrow;i++)
  {
    rngA[i][0]=rngA[i][0].replace(r1, rxR);//you might need a toString() in here before the replace.  Give me some data and I can check it out. 
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
}
```

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Hello, @Cooper! Like you say, I add toString() before replace and it works perfect! 5000 rows and 15 regexps in 21 seconds. Instead more than 6min with old function. Add data to question, so you can test it to. Thank you so much!

Comment: We could shave a little more off if we could come up with a simple way to get the regex's in there in an Array perhaps.  But 21 seconds versus 360 seconds that not bad.  I had spreadsheets that were taking several minutes to process and first time I went with using arrays they seem to process instantly.  So it's a big time saver.

Comment: Thanks for the data.  I always like to see my toys workl